# How to use MRCountryPickerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, appdelegate, uipickerviewcontroller

I am trying to implement MRCountryPicker for selecting Country Flag and Code.I have installed pods.

now i have no idea how can i get delegate method or how can i declare like this **"MRCountryPickerDelegate"**

for more detail check out

> https://github.com/xtrinch/MRCountryPicker
>
> class ViewController: UIViewController, **MRCountryPickerDelegate** {

i am getting this error

[image]

Thanks for your appreciation's and help..Thank you.

Comment: Did you import  it ? like `import MRCountryPicker`

Comment: Your full code can help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly,
First you must "import MICountryPicker",
then you write "MRCountryPicker"!! the library is "MICountryPicker", please check your spelling and make be sure that you write true.
example of MICountryPickerViewDelegate:

```
@objc public protocol MICountryPickerDelegate: class {
func countryPicker(picker: MICountryPicker, didSelectCountryWithName name: String, code: String)
@objc optional func countryPicker(picker: MICountryPicker, didSelectCountryWithName name: String, code: String, dialCode: String)
```

}